# How to get the inverse of this function?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Given the function:

```
(define (pp sxp)
  (cond
    ((null? sxp) sxp)
    ((list? sxp) (let-values (((args op) (split-at-right sxp 1)))
                   (cons (car op) (map pp args))))
    (else sxp)))
```

I have tried everything but not able to solve it.
Thank you!

Comment: What does this function do? What would the inverse do? "_I have tried everything...._" Share your best effort; what were you trying and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be very efficient, but you can do this

```lisp
(define (pf sxp)
  (cond
    ((null? sxp) sxp)
    ((list? sxp) (append (rest sxp) (list (first sxp))))
    (else sxp)))
```

You might want to watch out for lists of length 1.